# mongo PHP turns array into strings

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I'm adding data to MongoDB via MongoDB PHP driver.

For some reason The arrays from the $_POST are transferred into strings once they are in the DB.

The $_POST content: (printed with print_r - pasting only the relevant array

```
Array
(
...
...
   [ingredients] => [{u'amount': u'1 (14 ounce) can', u'name': u'black beans, drained', u'short_name': u'black beans'}, {u'amount': u'1 (8 ounce) jar', u'name': u'salsa', u'short_name': u'salsa'}]
...
)
```

The DB command is:
`$success = $collection->insert($_POST);`

And The result in the mongoDB (using the mongo shell) is:

```
{ ....
"ingredients" : "[{u'amount': u'1 (14 ounce) can', u'name': u'black beans, drained',     
u'short_name': u'black beans'}, {u'amount': u'1 (8 ounce) jar', u'name': u'salsa',     
u'short_name': u'salsa'}]", ..... }
```

How do I keep it as an array?

**Edit:**
@Salvador Dali's answer was correct. But for future reference the real problem was the array itself (coming from a POST rquest made by urllib2 in python)
the `u'string'` is failing PHP's json_decode. Fixing it to `"string"` solved the problem

Comment: mongo DB returns data as json u need to convert the data in the PHP level using `json_decode($data,true);` this will give u an array.

Comment: I'm querying this in mongo shell... I believe it is not true in this case...

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty you are wrong. He is doing this in shell, which means that he sees an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is simple. You are passing a string in you ingredients. So it appears as string in db.

To verify that I am correct run something `gettype($_POST['ingredients'])` and you will see that the result is `str`. Most probably your string is JSON.

You can parse it with `json_decode()` abd insert it into your mongo properly.

Comment: hmmm... you are correct - I do get string in gettype...
I have a code in there I thought solved it:
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {   
    
    if ($this->is_json($_POST[$key])) $_POST[$key] = json_decode($_POST[$key]) ; 
   }

But apparently it doesn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: true that... Although now I get null in mongo. I'll investigate. Your answer is good. thanks

Comment: @Boaz so what are you getting when you run json_decode on the string? Do you get array or no? If no, than the string is not a valid json.

Comment: apparently json_decode failed over the u''. Should be "" (the original POST request came from python code)