# urlencode of json data

Tags: python, json, urllib2

originating from a different question of mine, trying to find an elegant solution in the python code
([mongo PHP turns array into strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892629/mongo-php-turns-array-into-strings))

I have a valid json file, with an array of elements - all with "" (not a single ')

The following python code creates a POST request that causes PHP json_decode to fail
The $_POST array looks like so:

```
[{u'amount': u'1 (14 ounce) can', u'name': u'black beans, drained', u'short_name': u'black beans'}, {u'amount': u'1 (8 ounce) jar', u'name': u'salsa', u'short_name': u'salsa'}]
```

(with u'' in the strings)

The code that created this:

```
json_data = open(json_filename)
elems = json.load(json_data)
running_index=0
for elem in elems:
    data = urlencode(elem)
    result = urllib2.urlopen(base_url,data)
```

Any elegant way to make the data "PHP ready"?
Elegant == other than doing (which horrificly works):

```
data = data.replace("u%27","%22")
data = data.replace("%27","%22")
```

Comment: Is this working? `elem` in `for elem in elems` is the key of elems which is `dict` type generated by json

Comment: the json file is an array of json elements each of them is submitted to the server. You are missing the heart of the question...